# Getting the user profile pictures with pyTelegramBotAPI (JSON)

Tags: python, json, api, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

Here my code (Python):

```
import telebot
import time
import json

bot_token = "..."
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['myphoto'])
def send_welcome(message):
    number = bot.get_user_profile_photos(message.from_user.id)
    njson = json.loads(number)
    nlist = njson['photos']
    bot.reply_to(message, nlist[0].file_size)

while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)  # or just print(e) if you don't have logger,
        # or import traceback; traceback.print_exc() for print full info
        time.sleep(15)
```

Here a result of the JSON containing an array with the profile pictures of my account Telegram (**it is the result of the variable *"number"* in my code**):

```
{'total_count': 2, 'photos': [[<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at
0x7fc0fd9069a0>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906970>,
<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906a30>],
[<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906550>,
<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906eb0>,
<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906790>]]}
```

And here the involved classes from the pyTelegramBotAPI [link](https://pastebin.com/zkbvspMC)

But printing the variable njson or nlist[0] it don't show nothing. Where is the problem? I want to obtain the file_id of a single PhotoSize object inside this array (doing *photosizeName.file_id*, so i can download the picture with the regular default Telegram API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay close attention to this:

```
{'total_count': 2, 'photos': [[<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at
0x7fc0fd9069a0>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906970>,
<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906a30>],
[<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906550>,
<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906eb0>,
<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x7fc0fd906790>]]}
```

*photos* is an array of arrays. photos[0] is a list, then you'd have to go a level deeper and select one of its files, like this photos[0][0].

Anyway, you should add more info, is your program throwing an error?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it is [0][0]. But the error was: `in loads raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray). TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not UserProfilePhotos`, so it works doing `number.total_count` or `number[0][0]` because number is an object (UserProfilePhotos) with an array of photos.

Comment: Sorry, `number.photos[0][0].file_id` (UserProfilePhotos have an array of arrays "photos")